# Filtering a DateTime typed column by custom set options

Tags: datetime, filter, datagrid, infragistics, xamdatagrid

In my *XamDataGrid*, I can filter a column *Occasion* (which is of *DateTime* type) and the software presents me automatically with a bunch of appropriate choices (next year, this week, today etc.), which is great but not in this particular case.

Our need is to filter per year strictly, i.e. the full set of options to filter for should be e.g. 2013, 2014, 2015. Additionally, if possible, I'd like the set of available years to filter against to be dynamically created based on the actually available years in the columns. (Luckily, the data is loaded once and needs no further updates as the control is used as a viewer only.)

Suggestions? Googling for custom filter options for *DateTime* gave me nothing useful, regrettably...

Comment: Sounds like you will have to put your own custom filter in instead of relying on the built-in Infragistics selections.

Comment: Corporate decision to use Infragistics' component. Given the reputation of their software, I'm certain it can be done, probably with not much effort too. My problem is the ignorance of how-to's...

Comment: Infragistics XamDataGrid implementation of filter doesn't give that much flexibility. The options present in the drop down of filter popup are not easy to change and even if you manage to change them the you can not alter the filter logic. I've done the whole custom filter implementation for my application where i want to implement these xamdatagrid filter on my custom paging. But believe me it's not that simple. apart from the massive code it also took a quite few days to perfect the logic also (for datatype, convertes, bindings, maskings, value & display differnce etc.).